# Checkbox attributes in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to make a very basic calculator, and I want to have checkboxes to choose what operation to perform to the numbers. I am trying to make sure that when a box is checked all of the other boxes are unchecked. I am only testing this first, so thats's why Only one checkbox has the code for it. the function calculate is something I am not worried about, as I already tested it and it works. Thanks!

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="checkbox" value="+" onClick="calculate0();
document.getElementById("subtract").checked = "false";  ">
<input type="checkbox" value="-" id="subtract" onClick="calculate1()" checked="false">
<input type="checkbox" value="*" onClick="calculate2()">
<input type="checkbox" value="/" onClick="calculate3()">
<input type="text" id="num2">

<input type="text" id="answer" readonly>

</form>
```

Comment: Erm, that's what radio buttons are for.

Comment: @isherwood Sorry, Im new to the language, could you please explain what you are talking about?

Comment: Radio buttons are similar to checkboxes, except that only one can be checked at a time. You're attempting to replicate basic HTML behavior with JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/radio

Comment: Thanks! so for the type attribute should I put radio? @isherwood

Comment: Yup. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/radio for help with radio groups.

Comment: Those links lead to XUL radio docs, not HTML ones.

Comment: Anyone can post links. Feel free.

Comment: You could google all of this information easily. To be honest you're wasting your time asking people on some question and answer site.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons to choose the calculation mode and calculate it only with a "submit" button, or use submit - buttons instead. This is much more logical and looks better!

**EDIT:**

Use radio buttons like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="method" onclick="selectMethod('+');" />+ <br  />
  <input type="radio" name="method" onclick="selectMethod('-');" />- <br  />
  <input type="radio" name="method" onclick="selectMethod('*');" />* <br  />
  <input type="radio" name="method" onclick="selectMethod('/');" />/ <br  />
</form>

<script>
  var method = "+";

  function selectMethod(m) {
    method = m;
  }
</script>
```

Or use submit-buttons like this (it's the easiest way):

```
<input type="submit" value="+" onclick="calculate0;" />
<input type="submit" value="-" onclick="calculate1;" />
<input type="submit" value="*" onclick="calculate2;" />
<input type="submit" value="/" onclick="calculate3;" />
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to use radio buttons?

Comment: I've just added it. Try it out!

Comment: I see that with this you are making a variable for the + - * or /, but what would I do with the variable, to actually multiply the numbers together?

Comment: then you just nedd a button for calc: <input type="submit" onclick="if(method=="+") calculate0; else if(method=="-") calculate1; else if(method=="*") calculate2; else if(method=="/") calculate3;" />